# Search subarray and get parent array's index

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [sku_code_part] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Category
                    [sku_code_type] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => -
                    [sku_code_type] => 4
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => -
                    [sku_code_type] => 7
                )

        )
```

I'm trying to use search_array() to find sku_code_type = 7 and return it's parent key of 3; However search_array will only return the key for the value and not it's parent array's index.

What are the best options for this?

I'm thinking about looping through the array, but I'm not sure if this is going to be over doing it from a performance point of view.

Comment: Well, regardless, you have to loop through the array to search it.   array_search just simplifies the loop into a single function.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to determine. 

If I use: 

            foreach($this->request->post['sku_code_part'] as $key => $value) {
              if(in_array(7, $value)) {
                echo "Key is: " . $key; exit();
              }
            }

Is this overkill? 

Can it be achieved in much better way?

Comment: No, but in_array isn't what you should be using, you should just check the value of the specific index (sku_code_type)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it could be using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and then use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) from the result to get all the matching keys back in an array.

```
$result = array_filter($this->request->post['sku_code_part'], function($value, $key){
    return $value["sku_code_type"] === 7;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

print_r(array_keys($result));
```

Or as suggested use a foreach with `$key` and the `$value`

```
foreach ($this->request->post['sku_code_part'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value["sku_code_type"] === 7) {
        echo "sku_code_type: 7, parent key: $key\n";
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/50kEo)